# how to achive multiple categories in url working?

Tags: php, wordpress

Usually wordpress structure for category is as below.
http://ourdomain/category/categoryname/subcategoryname

but I want my structure to be like
http://ourdomain/categoryname1/categoryname2/categoryname3

I am not getting in which manner I can achive this thing?

I want to do is with this kind of url it should go in to some page in wp-content. after then code i will manage.

If some one has some idea regarding this direction?

Comment: So you want category/categoryname/subcategory/subSUBcategory/subSUBsubcategory? Or u want it to display 3 categories at once??

Comment: I want it to display 3 categories at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the following code i m able to achieve this thing.

```
function site_router() {
global $route,$wp_query,$window_title;
$bits =explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$route->class = $bits[1];
$route->method = $bits[2];
$route->prop1 = $bits[3];
$route->prop2 = $bits[4];
$route->prop3 = $bits[5];
$route->prop4 = $bits[6];
print_r($bits);
if ( $wp_query->is_404 ) {
$wp_query->is_404 = false;
include(get_template_directory() . "/home.php" ); // replace path_to_classes with the actual directory where you keep your class files
/* at the end of your classfile include, you can create the object as $myObject = new Class */
//$myObject->$route->method($route->prop1); // after calling the method, you can set a property in the object for the template

$template = locate_template('ur path/home.php');
$window_title = 'dynamically it will come';
if ($template) {
load_template($template);
die;
}
}
}
add_action( 'wp', 'site_router');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you colud do to show the 3 categories in the url, but to show 3 categories in the content you could modify some of the theme templates, maybe the loop or the category template to make it show the three of them:

```
$args = array('numberposts' => $Nposts, 'category' => $id_cat1);
$cat1_posts = get_posts($args);
//Loop to write all posts

$args = array('numberposts' => $Nposts, 'category' => $id_cat2);
$cat2_posts = get_posts($args);
//Loop to write all posts

$args = array('numberposts' => $Nposts, 'category' => $id_cat3);
$cat3_posts = get_posts($args);
//Loop to write all posts
```